# Calling specific iOS/Android routines from shared

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have this piece of code that runs in **iOS**:

```
  namespace Login.iOS
    {
    class Authenticate
    {
        public async Task LoginAsync()
        {
            var client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions

            {
                Domain = "difiore.auth0.com",
                ClientId = "Key goes here"
            });

                var loginResult = await client.LoginAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

As well as its equivalent for **Android**:

```
    namespace Login.Droid
    {
    class Authenticate
    {
        public async Task LoginAsync()
        {
            var client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions

            {
                Domain = "difiore.auth0.com",
                ClientId = "Key goes here"
            });

            var loginResult = await client.LoginAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

As both depends upon libraries that are specifically written for the platform, they must be platform specific.

Then I have the shared code that should call then:

```
    namespace Login
    {
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private void Login_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Authenticate());
        }
    }
}
```

But the code line

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new Authenticate());
```

is obviously wrong as it doesn't identify the routine to be called.

How can I call the platform specific routine from the shared one? That is the **Authenticate** class in IOS and Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an **interface** for calling platform specific class in shared or portable class using **Dependency** **Injection**. Follow this link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction. I hope this helps.